# How do I fix my old app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have old Java app in to controle my LED. I bought new phon and want install it. But I started Android Studio and i got info that "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g. editing,debugging)" will not work properly. I recently installed it on the beginning of the year and evryting work well andI haven't changed nothing. I add photo with informations. Someone konow what heppend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unVyh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the gradle version.